# Converting a sniffed scapy packet to bytes

Tags: struct, packet, scapy, unpack

When sniffing packets with scapy I can save them to a variable

```
sniffed = sniff(count=1)
```

Now I would like to see what's inside the packet by doing

```
print sniffed
```

or

```
print str(sniffed)
```

but all this gives me is something like the following:

```
������0�    E4h@@����������� l��
```

which isn't quite what I need. So how can I convert a sniffed packet into human readable Binary, or an array of Bytes or something more useful so that I can see what's inside? I have already tried using `struct.unpack(format, packet)` with formats like `"!B"`, but that does not seem to be the right solution, because the packet can be longer than one Byte or a Short or an Int.

---

Example for what I'm trying

```
>>> packet = sniff(count=1)[0]
>>> hexdump(packet)
0000   00 50 56 8E 00 0D 14 CC  20 16 E7 59 08 00 45 00   .PV..... ..Y..E.
0010   00 34 6B AB 40 00 40 06  C6 48 AC 11 8A E2 68 10   .4k.@.@..H....h.
0020   69 CC B5 47 00 50 E9 85  17 B0 BA EF 29 B2 80 10   i..G.P......)...
0030   01 DD 8D 58 00 00 01 01  08 0A 00 0E A2 C0 03 5D   ...X...........]
0040   9D 1C 
>>> packetByteArray = bytearray(repr(str(packet)))
>>> hex(packetByteArray[0])
'0x27'
>>>
```

But in the hexdump I can see that the first Byte is actually `0x00` and not `0x27`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably searching for [`scapy Hexdump(pkt)` or `hexraw(pkt)`](http://www.secdev.org/projects/scapy/doc/usage.html) or `repr(str(pkt))` for string encoded output. Note that sniff returns a list, not a single pkt.

If you want to access serialized packet bytes one by one just serialize the layers `str(pkt)` to get a python (char/byte)-string.

```
for b in str(pkt):
    print "char: %s ord/value: %d hex: %x"%(b,ord(b),ord(b))
```

Comment: `hexdump` gives me what I need, but how can I access the packets Bytes easily? Like `firstByteOfPacket = packet[0]`?. I'm currently trying to do this by `packetByteArray = bytearray(repr(str(packet)))` and then `firstByteOfPacket = packetByteArray[0]` expecting to receive the first Byte of the packet. Yet this gives me something that clearly is not the first Byte, as I can see from the `hexdump`. I'll add an example in my question.

Comment: see updated answer. just serialize the layer/packet and access any of the bytes as `str(pkt)[1]` to get the ascii char or `ord(str(pkt)[1])` to get the value. everything else is just a matter of representation.

Comment: Yes, that's what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

If you have already read the packet as pkt you may see bytes by time :

```
pktBytes=[]
pktTimes=[]
from datetime import datetime
#Read each packet and append to the lists.
for p in pkt:
    if IP in p:
        try:
            pktBytes.append(p[IP].len)
            pktTime=datetime.fromtimestamp(p.time)
            pktTimes.append(pktTime.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f"))
        except:
            pass

# Convert list to series
bytes = pd.Series(pktBytes).astype(int)

# Convert the timestamp list to a pd date_time with the option “errors=coerce” to handle errors.
times = pd.to_datetime(pd.Series(pktTimes).astype(str),  errors='coerce')

# Build the dataframe, set time as index
df  = pd.DataFrame({'Bytes': bytes, 'Times':times})
df = df.set_index('Times')

# See how it looks in 2 seconds sums
df.resample('2S').sum().plot()
```